# Does Xcode store files/settings in the global domain

Tags: xcode

I am having a [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16780366/xcode-greys-out-gpx-files-in-filebox?noredirect=1#comment24316947_16780366) with Xcode and I'm asking myself, if Xcode also saves files/settings in the global domain, meaning

- not in a user space like ~/me
- or probably inside the Xcode bundle
- or maybe within invisible .files

I'm talking about Xcode 4.6.2

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode uses the following directorys by default:

```
Derived Data:   ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
Snapshots:      ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Snapshots
Archives:       ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives
Documentation:  /Library/Developer/Documentation/DocSets
```

You can verify this in your Xcode's preferences:

[image]

You can have multiple Xcode Apps (generally different versions) installed at the same time. You can see which is the default by running `xcode-select`:

```
$ xcode-select -print-path
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Using Xcode-select to manually switch between versions of Xcode works great. You can have some issues if you manually install the command line tools .

Comment: Older version of Xcode used to store things (templates) etc in system-wide directories (eg /Library/Developer for templates).